# Manhwa in which the female protagonist was forced to grow up as a boy, then went to live alone and meets a group of people who protect her

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a manhwa in which the protagonist is an adult and tall woman but with a somewhat masculine appearance because she was forced to grow up as a boy in her family's house since childhood and was fed by her stepmother with potions that changed her hormones.

So she was disinherited and went to live alone, and that's where the story begins when important figures from different parts of the continent simply teleport close to her and start taking care of her, like an assassin, a wizard, a paladin, and there are two more I don't remember what they are. Anyway, they start to take care of her (who has her self-esteem on the floor) and in the future they make a "pact" with her to live together and protect her so that they can also become stronger and complete as they always wanted.

The group of people that protects her consists of three adult men, two young-looking and one older-looking, a pink boar, a young-looking woman and a very cute wolf, in addition to all the friends that the protagonist makes for her journey.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F. Where and when did you read this?

Comment: It's been a while and I don't remember, there weren't many chapters at the time so I decided to wait longer to read it later...

Comment: @Nyx - What did you mean by _"potions that **mechaim** with her hormones"_? I assume that word in bold is a typo, but which word did you mean to use?

Comment: Im so sorry! I'm actually Brazilian and sometimes while writing the corrector changes some words to English to Portuguese while I'm still writing so it's like...half English half Portuguese  lol. But I wanted to say that It changed her hormones...like...in a more educated way of saying that she doesn't have boobs like other female protagonists, she does look more like really skinny male leads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Aria of the Withered Branch](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/aria-of-the-withered-branch)***...?

> Alcheris Voygianna has had enough. Enraged, purposeless, and no longer wanting to go on after years of torment, she runs away with her stepmother's ring. But when she crushes the ring and falls asleep after failing to end her own life, she dreams of five demigods, who greet her in person a week later after she awakes! Their one request to her is this: live on so that they may live forever. In return, they promise to make her life worth living, but can they uphold that promise?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Aria of the Withered Branch."]

When Alcheris' mother died, her father brought his mistress and illegitimate daughter home to live with them, and forced Alcheris to live as a boy to ensure that his other daughter would succeed him as head of the household, as the family tradition dictated that the next head must be female.

As well as forcing Alcheris to outwardly present as male, her family also made her drink potions to prevent the bodily changes associated with puberty.

The father continued to favour his other daughter in subsequent years, largely ignoring Alcheris until she reached adulthood, at which point he gave her a recommendation letter for a civil service job in an embassy, and made it clear that she was no longer welcome in the family home.

Shortly before Alcheris left, her stepmother snatched the necklace she'd inherited from her mother and tossed it into the fireplace. Alcheris subsequently retrieved her charred necklace and stole her stepmother's ring on her way out of the house, then booked a room in an inn.

Upon entering her room, Alcheris vented her anger at the cruel treatment she'd received from her father and stepmother by hurling her stepmother's ring to the floor and stamping on it, breaking the jewel inside it. Tired of living, she drank a vial of poison, and laid down on the bed to die.

Rather than dying though, she had a dream about five people she'd never seen before; a little girl, a young woman, two young men, and an older man. When she awoke, she was informed that a week had passed, and that she had visitors, those being the five people she'd dreamed about.

They explained that they were 'Binah,' god-like beings with one setback; their immortal lifespans are bound to a 'token.' When Alcheris broke her stepmother's ring, she became their token, and as such, they need her to live forever in order to do so themselves, otherwise they'll only live to the age of 300.

As their lives depend on hers, these beings become a support system for Alcheris, and with their encouragement, she regains the will to live and takes the job her father arranged for her at the embassy. Alcheris continues to outwardly present as male at this time, but inwardly regards herself as female.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/aria-of-the-withered-branch/info).

Comment: YES THANK YOU SO SO SO SO MUCH!!!!!!!!